# Laravel Undefined variable when no entry is found in a table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, undefined

**MenusController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Menu;

    public function index(){

$menus = Menu::orderBy('created_at' , 'asc')->get();
return view('menus.index')->with('menus' , $menus);
}
```

**views/menus/index.blade.php**

```
 @if(count($menus) > 0) 
 @foreach($menus as $menu)
 <h4>{{$menu->category}}</h4> 
@endforeach 
@else 
 <p>No menu categories</p> 
 @endif
```

So I have a table in my database called “menus” and one of the columns is called “category”.

When I have an entry or entries in that table, my index page loads up normally with the entries from my database also showing up as expected. But if there is nothing on my menus table I will just get a “Undefined variable: menu...” error, but I expect it to just put out “No menu categories”.

Comment: @Jeto Sorry. I just typed this on my phone. I didn’t notice, but I assure you I am using valid quotes on my actual dev environment.

Comment: you must define in your model table name and fillable property in your model

Comment: Undefined variable:  menu or menus?

Comment: @VikasKatariya Just menu

Comment: Are you sure, the error is thrown from this code part?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@if(isset($menus) && count($menus)) 
    @foreach($menus as $menu)
    <h4>{{$menu->category}}</h4> 
    @endforeach 
@else 
    <p>No menu categories</p> 
@endif
```